# Icons are not displaying in BottomTabNavigator in react Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have been working on this simple mobile application. I am trying to show some icon on the bottom tab navigation instead of labels, but the icons are not showing up. Can someone help me figure out what the problem is?

I have been working on this simple mobile application. I am trying to show some icon on the bottom tab navigation instead of labels, but the icons are not showing up. Can someone help me figure out what the problem is?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

// Components
import Home from './src/components/home/Home'
import EventInfo from './src/components/common/eventInfo/EventInfo'
import Profile from './src/components/profile/Profile'
import Browse from './src/components/browse/Browse'
import Activity from './src/components/activity/Activity'

import homeIcon from './src/images/home.png'
import browseIcon from './src/images/home.png'
import activityIcon from './src/images/home.png'
import profileIcon from './src/images/home.png'

import myIcon from './src/images/activity.png';

const HomeStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home
  },
  EventInfo: {
    screen: EventInfo
  },
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Home', 
})

const BrowseStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Browse: {
    screen: Browse
  },
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Browse', 
})

const ActivityStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Activity: {
    screen: Activity
  },
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Activity', 
})

const ProfileStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Profile: {
    screen: Profile
  },
  EventInfo: {
    screen: EventInfo
  },
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Profile', 
})

const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home : HomeStackNavigator,
  Browse: BrowseStackNavigator,
  Activity: ActivityStackNavigator,
  Profile : ProfileStackNavigator,
},{
  initialRouteName:'Profile',
  defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBaricon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
        return (
          <Image 
            source={myIcon}
            style={{width:30, height:30}} 
          />
        );
    },
  }),
  tabBarOptions: {
  }
}

);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix your issue. You should also consider going through the docs [here](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/icon.html) and [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html) to understand better.

```js
...

const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Profile: {
    screen: Profile,
    navigationOptions: {
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
      <Icon
        name='rowing' />
      )
      }
  },
  EventInfo: {
    screen: EventInfo,
    navigationOptions: {
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <Icon
      name='rowing' />
      )
    }
},
}, {
  initialRouteName:'Profile',
});

...
```

Kindly let me know if this helped.

Comment: @Alex Cool. Please do accept it as the correct answer then.